# Using MDF file on Azure Data Studio (MacBook)

Tags: azure-sql-database, mdf

I'm trying to open a MDF file on Azure Data Studio, I'm trying to use this code to attach the database but i cant unfortunately. I keep getting the error **Invalid object name 'Vetsv2'.** even though Im specifying the data extension on my laptop.

````
ON  
( NAME = UniData,  
    FILENAME = '/Users/ak/Downloads/UniData/UniData.mdf' )  
 LOG ON  
( NAME = UniData,  
    FILENAME =  '/Users/ak/Downloads/UniData/UniData.ldf')  

Select * from UniData;```
````

Comment: Azure Data Studio is a client.  What you are pasting is T-SQL.  So, it looks like you are trying to use SQL Server on Linux.  If so, your tag is incorrect.  Either way, I suggest you post a complete repro for people to try to help you once you specify the environment fully.

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting to the Azure SQL database from Azure Data Studio for MAC:

Azure SQL database doesn't support [attach a database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database?view=sql-server-2017#TsqlProcedure).

[image]

Hope this helps.